# When should I use a CSS class over inline styling?

Tags: html, css

I have some hidden divs that I show via JavaScript when a button is clicked. Right now, I'm hiding them with by using inline styling (i.e. `style="display:none;"`).

This works, but are there general rules or guidelines to follow to determine if I should use inline styles or styling via stylesheets and class selectors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For web apps (vs web pages) why not put scripts and css inline?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/240734/for-web-apps-vs-web-pages-why-not-put-scripts-and-css-inline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best Practice is to avoid using in-line styles where possible so Yes I would suggest you use the class="hidden"

Check out this link for more information on best practices with inline styles vs external:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: where ( 1 ) {
    use_CSS_classes() ;
    }

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not? For example:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <style type="text/css">
   body
   {
   background-color:#d0e4fe;
    }
   .hidden
   {
    display:none;
   }
  p
  {
   font-family:"Times New Roman";
   font-size:20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="hidden">This CSS example is hidden!</div>
  <p>This paragraph is visble.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I like inline-styles while designing in-browser since I don't have to go back and remove selectors that I don't end up using. It's also quicker for me to see what styles are applied to what and from where. I actually have never run into problems leaving them like that for one-off styles (e.g., if I need a custom padding on one specific DIV) until I need to customize these styles for mobile in which case I'll have to remove some so I can override them with my media-queries. But, if I end up using the same set of rules on multiple items I almost always create a class for it. **So - in a nut shell, I use them for one-offs that I don't need to override using media queries.**

As a disclaimer, this is my opinion based on my years of experience and not necessarily based on best practice. If I'm coming into a project I will always try to use their established best practices, which is typically not to use inline-styles, although they do make my life easier both as the initial developer and as the later maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

> There are inline styles on some markup that you absolutely can't
>   remove, but you need to override what those styles are. This could be
>   markup that is being inserted onto the page from foreign JavaScript or
>   perhaps generated from the bowels of a CMS that you cannot control
>   easily.

we CAN override inline styles directly from the stylesheet. Take this example markup:

HTML

```
<div style="font-size: 40px;">
The inline styles Example. </div>
```

We can fight that with this:

CSS

```
div[style] {
   font-size: 20px !important;
}
```